# Apache Drill Parser error while creating table from simple select of JSON file

Tags: apache-drill

I get parser error while creating table from SQL query of JSON file in apache Drill.

```
USE dfs.tmp;
CREATE Table myt AS
(SELECT KVGEN(repo)[1] reponame FROM dfs.`f:\DemoData\201901-000000000000.json`
WHERE STRPOS(payload,'ARM') >0)
```

error:

```
Org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: PARSE ERROR: Encountered ";" at line 1, column 12. Was expecting one of: <EOF> "." ... "[" ... SQL Query USE dfs.tmp; ^ CREATE Table myt AS (SELECT KVGEN(repo)[1] reponame FROM dfs.`f:\DemoData\201901-000000000000.json` WHERE STRPOS(payload,'ARM') >0)
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you try your query with a linebreak between the definition of workspace and the actual query?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to submit to queries, but Drill doesn't support submitting several queries via a single form in Drill Web UI.
Please create Jira ticket to improve it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL.

You can use Drill SqlLine (Drill shell). It hasn't this limitation.